# Unable to return value from a recursive function

Tags: python, return

While trying to get value of a key in a nested dictionary by ignoring the hierarchy, it always returns `None`.

```
def nested(d,key):
    for i in d.keys():
        if i == key:
            return d[i]
        elif isinstance(d[i], dict):
            nested(d[i],key)

j = {'hello': {'foo': {'bar': {'world':'yeay'}}}}
print(nested(j,'world'))
```

The expected answer is `yeay` of course, But what am I missing?

Comment: `return nested(d[i],key)`

Comment: @JimStewart right! that's the correct answer..

Comment: Thanks. I voted to close this though, because this is a simple omission that's unlikely to help others. I'd suggest you delete the question if you agree.